# Can anyone tell me what your Pi says?

Tags: raspbian, cmdline.txt

If you go to the terminal on your Pi and write down sudo nano /boot/codling.txt and write what it says exactly or take a picture because on my Pi it doesn't say the device rotation nor the fps etc please help and tha
nk you

Comment: What "device" is it that you are expecting to have a "rotation"?  Do you mean the camera image orientation? The pi cam is configured after booting from software running on the OS, not by anything in `/boot`.  You need to look at the basic documentation, see, e.g., `raspistill --help`.  There are other ways to use and configure it but this will at least outline the possibilities.

Comment: I want to rotate the screen display on my Pi because I have this 7 inch touchscreen(the official raspberry screen(new)) and my screen is upside down and wanted to flip it round. On my tv it displays perfectly.

Comment: Okay, so maybe asking a question about how to do that specifically would be a better idea.  Q.v. the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) <- does not improve your chances at getting help.

Answer (score 3):

Which OS did you install on your Pi? Mine doesn't have a /boot/codling.txt. I am running Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 and my /boot dir has the following files:

```
bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb
bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb
bcm2708-rpi-cm.dtb
bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
bootcode.bin
cmdline.txt
config.txt
COPYING.linux
fixup_cd.dat
fixup.dat
fixup_db.dat
fixup_x.dat
issue.txt
kernel7.img
kernel.img
LICENCE.broadcom
LICENSE.oracle
os_config.json
overlays
start_cd.elf
start_db.elf
start.elf
start_x.elf
```

Comment: I don't have a clue I just started and did what this magazine said: "The Complete Raspberry Pi Manual"